# How to remove Nulls from Save As in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have created a variable that is type table inside a stored procedure. At the end of the procedure I am selecting all the rows in the table and displaying them. When I right click on the headers and select "Save As" it allows me to change the type to All Files and save the file as a text file. This works fine except that the columns that have NULLS in them saves as NULLS. I want it to fill NULLs in with spaces.

I've been trying to find a way to create a file using a stored procedure but most things indicate to use SSIS but I can't figure out how to use SSIS with a variable that is a table instead of using an actual table.

If I could either replace nulls with spaces or use a stored procedure to do the same thing it would be great. I can not use tab or comma delimited as the final product has to be a flat file that each column uses the same amount of characters as is declared in the column headers. Padded with spaces.

Thanks for any help you are able to offer.

Cheers

P.S. I am using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Comment: Add default values of empty strings to the table definition.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I actually had the columns defaulted to ' ' but part of the Stored Procedure will reset the column back to NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last thing you do in the stored procedure is Select * From TempTable then you can use that SP in an OleDb source component.  Change from Table or View to Sql Command and use the Exec (sp_SomeName) syntax.  This will create a pipe that you can connect to a destination component, such as flat file.

I have seen many issues over the years doing Save Results As...  I will only use this for informal 'quick check' files and not for anything considered 'live' or 'production' data.

Here is a good blog that also shows how to use parameters.
http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out!  I didn't realize I could change the source to the stored procedure

Comment: Thanks Joe!  I was able to get a flat file created from SSIS and I believe the data looks like I want it to look.  NULLS were replaced with spaces; I set it to be ragged fixed width.  Now I just need to figure out how to trigger the SSIS package through a Stored Procedure and have it rename the file each time.   Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I am glad I could help :).  If you are using the SSIS catalog it is pretty easy easy to call from tsql including an SP.  If not there are many examples of ways to do it depending on your deployment model.  For file naming it could be as simple as an expression in the connection manager properties or if needed you can use an execute sql task to get a value using tsql or a script task to write custom code.  The key is the setting the connection manager connection string property.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to do this would be to convert the `NULL`s to spaces in your `SELECT` statement.

`SELECT COALESCE(yourcolumn, '')`

Put the `COALESCE` clause around every column that has `NULL`s in it.

[Using COALESCE article link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)